# Netbeans Won't Start After Accidentally Deleting etc/netbeans.conf

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

I unfortunately mistakenly completely deleted my netbeans.conf from the /etc/ folder in my main Netbeans folder.

I am on Ubuntu, and the program now will not start at all.

Does anyone have a config from Netbeans 7.3.1 or know how to "regenerate" this file?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if its in the trash, if not, might be re-install time.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't there. Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any way to maintain my list of Netbeans projects, or will I just have to manually reimport each one? Thanks.

Comment: Your list of projects should be in your own user files below `HOME/.netbeans` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example of a netbeans.conf file content:

```
# ${HOME} will be replaced by JVM user.home system property
netbeans_default_userdir="${HOME}/.netbeans/6.9"

# Options used by NetBeans launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches:
netbeans_default_options="-J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m 
-J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dnetbeans.winsys.statusLine.in.menuBar=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"

# Default location of JDK, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir>:
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20"

# Additional module clusters, using ${path.separator} (';' on Windows or ':' on Unix):
#netbeans_extraclusters="/absolute/path/to/cluster1:/absolute/path/to/cluster2"
```

Applies to: NetBeans IDE 4.x, 5.x, 6.x, 7.x
Platforms: All

Source: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf

Comment: Thanks, but there is no way that is 100% cross-platform, as Unix-based OS's don't have the notion of lettered drives

Comment: Ah ok, thats true, I just take the "Platforms: All" from the netbeans wiki site. Does this solved your problem? Probably you could mark it as right ;)

Comment: Let me try to put this in an empty netbeans.conf folder and change the windows path to an Ubuntu compatible one, and then I will let you know.

Comment: Actually, Netbeans still will not start even after making that. I guess I will just reinstall it.